# Upstart to Systemd

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, upstart

We have a **.conf** file named **private-api.conf** in the location **/etc/init** ,
So my file location is - `/etc/init/private-api.conf`

The contents of my file is as following -

```
# start when server starts
start on runlevel [23456]
# Stop when server shuts down/reboots
stop on shutdown

#Respawn the process if it crashes
#If it respawns more than 10 times in 5 seconds stop
respawn
respawn limit 10 5

#expect fork

script
    cd /home/ubuntu/private-api && exec java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=stage private-api-SNAPSHOT.jar > private-api.log 2>&1
end script
```

The next Command I need to fire is -

```
sudo initctl reload-configuration
```

After which I am supposed to run the Service, using the following command -

```
service private-api start/stop/restart/status
```

**I get the following error when I do** - 
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

I found that in Ubuntu 16.04 upstarts don't work and have moved to Systemd now,
And that the Systemd file needs to be in the location - `/etc/systemd/system`, with the file extension `.service`
After which to run the Systemd following 2 commands need to be fired -
1. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
2. `sudo systemctl start xyz.service`

I am referring the following links -
1. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers 
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files

Here's what I've achieved so far using the above refs -

```
[Unit]
Description=Upstart for Private API
After=network.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/private-api
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -classpath home/ubuntu/private-api/private-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=stage > home/ubuntu/private-api/private-api.log 2>&1
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=120s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I reloaded my Systemd service -
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
But when I check service status, I get absolute path errors -

```
sudo systemctl status private-api.service

    Apr 05 08:48:56 ip-10-10-1-153 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/private-api.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -classpath /home/ubuntu/private/astro-private-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev > private.log 2>&1
Apr 05 08:48:56 ip-10-10-1-153 systemd[1]: private-api.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Apr 05 08:49:07 ip-10-10-1-153 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/private-api.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -classpath /home/ubuntu/private/astro-private-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev > private.log 2>&1
Apr 05 08:49:07 ip-10-10-1-153 systemd[1]: private-api.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Apr 05 08:51:40 ip-10-10-1-153 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/private-api.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -classpath /home/ubuntu/private/astro-private-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev > /home/ubuntu/private/private.log 2>&1
Apr 05 08:51:40 ip-10-10-1-153 systemd[1]: private-api.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Apr 05 09:17:41 ip-10-10-1-153 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/private-api.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -classpath /home/ubuntu/private/astro-private-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev > /home/ubuntu/private/private.log 2>&1
Apr 05 09:17:41 ip-10-10-1-153 systemd[1]: private-api.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Apr 05 09:17:59 ip-10-10-1-153 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/private-api.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -classpath /home/ubuntu/private/astro-private-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev > /home/ubuntu/private/private.log 2>&1
Apr 05 09:17:59 ip-10-10-1-153 systemd[1]: private-api.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

Can someone help me convert my current upstart .conf script?

Comment: I'm chipping-away at the same damn thing. I just found this which looks promising. At least, for me: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/convert-run-at-startup-script-from-upstart-to-systemd-for-ubuntu-16

Comment: FWIW, the manpages systemd.service and systemd.exec are really all what you need. The documentation is pretty extensive and complete.

Comment: hi, I've updated my question, can you help find the flaw in my Systemd service? My upstart script is also included in the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have already set the WorkingDirectory, you can directly use the command from your script.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=stage > private-api.log 2>&1
```

Hopefully this works.